# Disable specific dates in react DatePicker with API in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, arrays, api, date, datepicker

Have been trying to disable dates from API. Have tried a variety of different methods and have not yet found a solution.

```
    this.state = {
      reservations: [],
    }
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    pocService.getReservations()
      .then((response) => {
        this.setState({ reservations: response.data })
      })

  };
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <DatePicker isValidDate={this.state.reservations} />
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: I suggest you add links to the documentation of your API.

Comment: https://github.com/victorialewski/Reservation

Answer (score 1):

Try the filter date prop like below

```
() => {
  const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(null);
  const isWeekday = (date) => {
    const day = getDay(date);
    return day !== 0 && day !== 6;
  };
  return (
    <DatePicker
      selected={startDate}
      onChange={(date) => setStartDate(date)}
      filterDate={isWeekday}
      placeholderText="Select a weekday"
    />
  );
};
```